# received a review audit in triage queue for a question that I already acted on before outside of the queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, triage

I received [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6823420) in Triage. Looked like possible spam and I guess I already flagged it as spam before since when I clicked on "unsalvageable" it greyed out the area of spam/offensive flag saying that I already used this type of flag on the question. So I just voted to close as too broad and passed my first triage audit.

But is this a bug? Should we be given reviews/audits that we already acted on previously? I don't think we receive posts that we've already acted on in other queues.

Comment: No weirder than [receiving the same audit twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167635/why-would-you-give-me-the-same-review-audit-twice).

Comment: I think if we're going to audit, it needs to be with good clear posts. The quality of the audit post collection has declined substantially in the last few weeks.