# First failed triage audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

I can't say that I didn't [see this coming](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2947971#2947971)...

I received my [4th review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6823800) out of 14 total reviews so far today in the triage queue, and I failed it. The other three audits, which I passed, can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284311/received-a-review-audit-in-triage-queue-for-a-question-that-i-already-acted-on-b).

[image]

It's pretty obvious that the "thanks" and "any help would be appreciated" should be removed from the question, so I clicked on "Should Be Improved" and failed the audit.

Should I be less picky in the triage queue when it comes to things like that?

Comment: JPEG, and squeezed... My eyes!

Comment: Please link directly to the audit. *stabs eyes out*

Comment: Less picky? Yes. I wouldn't worry about "thanks" and "any help would be appreciated" in triage. Especially since you missed the "My VBA skills are not so good, just started learning it 2 weeks ago" which I think are more annoying than "thanks".

Comment: @MattBurland: More annoying? Yes. Less useful? Not quite; "thanks" is of literally no value whatsoever, but "I have two weeks' experience" is a noisy way of saying something less concisely expressed as "simple basic explanations please, in case you didn't assume that already".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your question, I'm just gonna post a screenshot of the instructions for Triage:

[image: Looks OK for questions that can be found, understood and answered as-is]

Lemme know if that's unclear.

Comment: I recommend wearing it on your forehead.

Comment: If you follow Shog's recommendation, I also recommend a mirror.

Comment: Just to use a specific example to make sure I'm clear on it, I just marked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103131/print-lottery-number-in-sam4s-er-682-cash-machine) as unsalvageable but maybe shouldn't because the author may edit it to include code and a link to the printer documentation?

Comment: Do you honestly think that's at all likely, @PeterJ? I don't. Review looks fine.

Comment: This is unclear. Can you please spell out why OP was wrong and link to the guidance that classifies it as such?