# Triage audit failed but the "guidance above" isn't visible anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, triage

I just failed a Triage review audit (a lousy one, which I downvoted, but that's beside the point) and the wording in the audit failure box is misleading.  It says:

> we've already handled this appropriately -- but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind **the guidance above**.

[image: Audit fail wording]

I assume the "guidance" referred to is the list of triage actions [as pictured in shog9's post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284316/541091) but by the time the failure message is shown, the guidance is gone.

I could shrug it off and assume it means to keep in mind the guidance above the review *as I'm doing it*, but the ***please take a minute to look it over closely*** implies I should be able to see the guidance while I sheepishly look into why I failed.

So, can we have keep the review action guidance on the screen while the audit failure is showing?

Comment: Woops, forgot about that. There's supposed to be specific guidance on how the audit should've been reviewed listed right after "**you didn't pass**".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should now see guidance when failing an audit:

[image]

Comment: Let's hope I never do.