# Why was flagging this post as 'Needs More Focus' considered inappropriate?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-questions

[This question in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30235672) clearly asks multiple questions at the end, so I flagged it as 'Needs More Focus', as *"The question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."* But I appeared to have failed the audit.

> [image]

It says "keeping in mind the guidance above" but did not provide any guidance or explanation as to why my action was inappropriate ([this appears to have been an issue before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284428/triage-audit-failed-but-the-guidance-above-isnt-visible-anymore)).

I don't understand why I didn't pass. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Because currently, the question doesn't have any downvotes and no close votes, thus the system assumes it's a "good question".

Comment: The question seems a bit borderline, but not really bad imo. While the question 1, question 2 and question 3 at the end make it seem like multiple questions, the question essentially is: "what does this change mean and why was it made?". That still seems like 2 questions, but it's no more 2 questions than "why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?", the questions are so strongly related that it's fine to ask them both imo

Comment: It lacks focus. (What is its question? It is not 1 question.)

Comment: Please use text, not images, for what can be given in text.

Answer (score 2):

Just the fact that a question contains multiple questions or multiple question marks does not mean it should be closed and/or split up.

Especially questions about language design, but also questions like *"Is this the way to do this? Or can I improve it by fooing the bar?"* (that's two questions for who's keeping count) can actually benefit from having all related doubts listed together, so an answerer can pick any starting point and work their way to a complete answer to all separate (but related!) questions.

If the questions are unrelated (*"How can I generate an email message with plaintext and HTML?"* and *"How can I send an .eml file through GMail?"* are entirely unrelated questions), then sure, closing (or commenting) might be the way to go.

The question you show contains very related questions about the specific implementation of a particular language design detail. It's fine.

Comment: By *"doubts"*, do you mean *"[questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)"*?

Comment: @Peter I doubt it.