# How do review audits work in Triage?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, triage

What are review audits; how is the correct action determined and what happens if you fail one?

Comment: I'm just curious why so many of you are marking this too broad when I have specific questions

Comment: Also, reading over [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) should help answer your first two questions.

Comment: Ok, I limited it to the last one

Comment: Kudos for taking the feedback to heart. :) This particular question is answered in the FAQ section of Meta Stack Exchange. The post in question is [here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) It currently does not address Triage, however, but [here's a post that does.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278440/are-there-audits-in-the-triage-review-queue/278512#278512) Triage is relatively new, and so are the audits, so those will likely be added to the FAQ later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are currently two types of audits:

- **Known-good** audits are generated from posts that have a lack of negative signal (close votes, downvotes), and a plethora of positive signals (upvotes, views, actions from high-rep users).

  Failing to mark a known-good audit as "Looks OK" may be considered a failure; marking it as "unsalvageable" will certainly fail it.
- **Known-bad** audits are generated from posts that were deleted for being spam.

  Failing to mark a known-bad audit as "unsalvageable" may be considered a failure; marking it as "Looks OK" will certainly fail it.

A failed audit will give you a stern warning. A sufficient number of failures in a short period of time may result in a temporary removal of reviewing privileges.

#### See also: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: What do you mean by may fail it if I fail to do the right action without doing the completely wrong action?

Comment: Strictly-speaking, both types of audits have only one choice that is correct - but "needs improvement" may pass either one depending on how we've configured the system. Eventually, expect both to fail.

Comment: @Shog9: "may pass"?  As in, there's some percent-chance to pass, or some arbitrary hidden variable that makes it a pass?  That seems counter to the educational role of audits, as people only get feedback about their errors some of the time, and other times the same action passes.

Comment: Read up - second comment, @JeffreyBosboom.

Comment: @Shog9: I was replying to that comment.  I don't understand why you'd choose to let "needs improvement" sometimes pass the audits given there is only one correct choice.

Comment: Lack of confidence in the "known-good" selection logic, @Jeffrey. We've beefed it up considerably, but... still a bit gun-shy. As I said, this behavior is temporary - the purpose is to gather information on which audits are less-than-clear-cut.

Comment: @Shog9 Tracking which audits are questionable (failed the most by users who pass most audits, or whatever metric) seems orthogonal to letting some wrong answers pass for opaque reasons.  But we're veering into chat, so I'll wait for you to explain yourself if/when you present the data you collected and/or the triage feature "graduates from beta".

Comment: In my opinion, "Should Be Improved" should not be considered a failing response for many of the audits that have been presented to me that were from the *Known-Good* pool. Several of the ones I have seen definitely could use an edit for formatting, grammar, spelling, etc. Each such *automatically chosen* question/answer might be a good question/answer, with good content, but that does not mean that they actually reach the level which a conscientious reviewer would rate them as "Looks OK". Unfortunately, even an edit by a high rep user is not sufficient to guarantee such issues are solved.

Comment: @Makyen See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284315/first-failed-triage-audit -- it seems if a post is answerable as-is, it Looks OK, even if editing could make it better.