# What does a triage review audit with correct answer "Requires Editing" mean?

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

I had never heard of review or review audits before today. I just started out doing reviews. I got my first review audit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937994/learning-algorithms-on-myself-how-do-you-implement-tuples-in-java). Since I thought the post could be improved, I tried to add a comment giving what I thought the improvement should be. Then I got an error saying my comment could not be posted. I tried again several times, but got the same error. So I opened the question. I was a little surprised to see it already had an accepted answer and was more than 2 weeks old, but I needed to finish the triage so I added the comment and then clicked the "Requires Editing" button.

I was then told that I had passed the test.

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You **passed**.

First of all, I tried to find out why this question was selected for the review audit. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172) on SE Meta talks about other review types but not triage, whereas [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285708/191761) on this Meta talks about other review actions but not "Requires Editing". So I am still a little confused why I passed the test by taking this action, given that this was a question which already had an accepted answer?

Secondly, I don't think I did anything wrong by adding the comment, as I was a bit confused as to what was going on. But is there a way we can streamline the process to stop people trying to add such comments, for example disallowing posting of the comment even if they open the question in a new browser tab? Or is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: Well ask yourself this: if a question is answered, does that automatically mean that it no longer would require editing? Keeping in mind that we're collecting **quality** questions and answers.

Comment: I agree with you, but other answers on meta linked from my question only refer to the status of the question (such as VTC, deleted, etc). Since this question was in good standing, I wanted to know why it was flagged as "requires editing" on review audit. Presumably there is some way for the system to determine such questions, i.e. they are not manually selected.

Comment: Also, according to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284316/191761 if the question is answerable "as-is", it should be tagged "Looks OK" for the purpose of review audits. Since the question was actually answered "as-is", this seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: I see your point, and now I'm curious for an answer to this question as well. But I wonder what would have happened if you had picked "looks ok". Would you then have failed the audit? Perhaps you would only fail this audit if you pick "unsalvageable".