# Received a review audit in which I was one of the original close voters, even though this bug was supposedly already fixed

Tags: bug, disputed-review-audits

I recently received [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15786998) on the following question:
[Trying to find pattern in an array (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774457/trying-to-find-pattern-in-an-array-python)

The audit itself is a good example of a lousy question that should be closed (it's basically a zero-effort requirements dump). However, I was one of the original close voters.

I did notice that [a similar issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284311/received-a-review-audit-in-triage-queue-for-a-question-that-i-already-acted-on-b) was already raised for the Triage queue, and it was tagged as being complete; that being the case, I'm a little confused as to why this happened. Is this a separate issue?

Comment: Different queue, different code. These kinds of changes often don't get added to other review queues because they're not always relevant to other review queues. That change was specific to the Triage review queue. Your audit was in the Close Votes review queue.

Comment: @animuson I suspected as much. In that case, the Close queue has the same bug.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203663/post-i-voted-down-and-close-is-shown-to-me-as-known-good-audit

Comment: @animuson Shouldn't all queues not serve up an audit in which you already had interactions with that post?

Comment: @NathanOliver No. That doesn't matter in all queues. For example, I can't imagine why you'd want to block someone reviewing Suggested Edits just because they've edited it before, or why you'd want to block someone from potentially reopening a question they've closed before. Etc. There are *some* checks for places where you've already completed the only action you can take, but those checks are different for every queue and there's no global fix for them.

Comment: @animuson Makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @NathanOliver besides - just imagine the extra level of embarrassment if you end up failing an audit and then realise you helped put it there in the first place :-P